# ETH not showing up

Tags: contract-development, metamask, ropsten, mycrypto

To help me get started learning how to create contracts, I had 1 ETH sent from the Ropsten Ethereum Faucet to my MetaMask address.  It arrived fine, but when I tried to send it to MyCrypto address it has never showed up -- after almost a whole day, although the Status line says Success.  I notice that at the top it says, "[ This is a Ropsten Testnet transaction only ]" in red.  Is it refusing to go through because of something to do with Ropsten? https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe20eff34a5a8d60de3e61d2f9a914df9be507ea6a37d23dd86cd1f3ca37aa050

Previously I had sent ETH from my Uphold wallet to the same MyCrypto address, and that came through in short order.

You might ask why am I bouncing around between MyCrypto and MetaMask?  Ha, I started by watching a YouTube video about Mist that had been produced 3 years ago, not knowing Mist has been shut down.  It's too bad that people leave out-of-date content laying around to confuse people, which has easily happened to me!  I was then referred to MyCrypto and then Remix (which recommended MetaMask as a wallet platform).

Answer (score 1):

The red message "[ This is a Ropsten Testnet transaction only ]" is not an error but only a reminder you are using a testnet and ethers have no value on it.

Your transaction succeeded, you sent 0.998341 ETH to 0x824a08cc18eceBD5211EA1AdD1eda219ee16c642 .

Here you can see your current balance (1.998341 ETH) : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x824a08cc18ecebd5211ea1add1eda219ee16c642

Are you sure you're connected to the Ropsten network when checking your balance on MyCrypto ? The default network is the main network.

Comment: Thanks, that was it; I was on the main network!  As it is, I also have 0.0188 ETH on the mainnet.  Can I move it from there to the Ropsten net?  Also, can that then all be transferred to my MetaMask wallet?

Comment: You can't move ETH from mainnet to Ropsten because that's two separate chains.

Comment: Does that mean the only way to fund the Ropsten testnet is with their 1 ETH gifts?

Comment: Their are many websites which distribute Ropsten faucets. You can try this one : https://faucet.ropsten.be/

Comment: Or this one https://teth.bitaps.com/ for exemple. However your requests will always be limited in quantity, most of the time to 1 ETH, as the number of faucets is limited itself.